# PPC advertising publishing options on on an Ajax/Dynamic site?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, ajax

Does anyone know of an advertising programme which will allow a highly ajax-ified site to be monetized?

Google seems to have ramped down its Ajax-Adsense experiment (no longer accepting applications).  And the techniques required to hack vanilla-Adsense into an ajax site seem to be against Google's terms.

I'm looking for a program that will allow me to dynamically insert ads into a page and control where they are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

One option I've used is to use banner ads from companies advertising through various affiliate marketing organizations, such as Commission Junction. You can find some that are PPC but most will be pay-per-action or a commission. You can even create faux-Adsense from these links if you have a little web dev knowledge.

eBay's EPN is another option but they can be picky about the sites they accept. For the past two years or so they've been sort of PPC with some backend calculations based on "visitor engagement".

Comment: Thanks +1. My experience with commission based ads has been less than great - but this is definitely an option.

Comment: It's really based a lot on the niche and the advertiser. I've had some do OK and others haven't done that well at all.